# How does one compile scala with bigger tuples?

Tags: scala

I want to compile Scala distribution with bigger limit for number of tuple arguments - for example, 50 instead of 22. (and function/case class/etc limits upped as well)

I assumed that those TupleN, FunctionN and the like are generated at compile-time. But in sources directory, I found all those Tuple1 to Tuple22, with comment that they are generated.

Also, I found src/build/genprod.scala file, which seems to be the needed file. But what is the right way to run it?

I changed `MAX_ARITY` in `genprod` and changed `MaxFunctionArity` in `Definitions.scala`, what else I need to change to make it work?

And is it possible to use the resulting scala distribution with sbt? Or are there some fundamental problems with that?

**NOTE:** I completely understand that it is not very good to try to work around tuple problems this way, but in this case it's more of an educational project.

**EDIT:** Well, it gets interesting. Since scala compiler is bootstraped, I can't compile it with bigger tuples, since old compiler enforces 22 limit. So it seems that first I need to create a compiler with that limit increased, and only after that compile in more tuples. How can I do it?

**EDIT2:** Now I have a problem - I tried to increase MaxFunctionArity and run `ant replacestarr-opt`, but then it fails with `scala.Function23 not found`. If I try adding scala.Function23 and the like, it fails to compile at all. Is there a way to fix it?

**EDIT3:** I tried to execute the commands in the following order:

```
ant build
# increase MaxFunctionArity
ant build
ant replacelocker
# generate TupleN classes
ant build

# this fails
ant replacelocker
```

The `ant replacelocker` seems to fail because `starr` compiler is used, and it still does not allow more than 22 arguments.

I tried to replace starr:

```
ant build
# increase MaxFunctionArity
ant build
ant replacelocker
ant replacestarr # failed
```

but this failed with `scala.Function23 not found`. Seems to be a deadlock - I need to change that `MaxFunctionArity` *and* generate classes, but I can't do that simultaneously, and if I try to separate those actions I get a failure.

Is there some way to resolve that?

**EDIT4:** I forgot to mention that in this experiment I'm torturing Scala 2.9.2, as it is the last stable version.

**EDIT5:** Since I actually managed to build `quick` compiler with big tuples using `locker` compiler, I expected that there was some problem with `starr` layer.

So I tried to do the following (without altering anything):

```
ant build
ant replacelocker
ant replacestarr
```

And the last command failed with

```
Unable to find jar:file:/home/platon/Input/sources/scala-tupled/lib/scala-compiler.jar!/scala/tools/ant/sabbus/antlib.xml
```

Now that's strange, why it can't build itself?

Comment: Are nested tuples insufficient for you?  If you nest 22 `Tuple22` items in a `Tuple22`, you can make a pretty big pseduo-tuple.

Comment: @dhg - No, they are not. As far as I know, scala-query needs flat tuples to work. And as I said, that is more of educational project, so I'm exploring :)

Comment: @Rogach I'm not familiar with scala-query, but it can't possibly discriminate between tuples and other kinds of `Product`, so you could just write a wrapper of `Seq` that extends `Product`, or, if you truly need a heterogeneous collection, you could wrap `HList` from [shapeless](http://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame - For scalaquery to work properly and without too much boilerplate, I need to have a case class with fields for each column in table. The problem with case classes that 22 is fundamental limitation, period. (and scalaquery actually does discriminate between tuples, you can take a look on the source). And as I said, this is educational, so I'm just looking how far I can go with this.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame - Actually, right now it seems that I can go quite far (if I compile scala's layers in the right order). But the last build failed with StackOverflowException, since I tried to create tuple of size 222 :) I'm trying to throw some more memory at it now.

Comment: @som-snytt - I can't generate them first, since then compilation fails with "implementation restriction". I have to bump Max first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at 2.10, where there is max arity for Product, Tuple and Function.

I modified genprod to make the change in three steps:

1. ProductN, and caseless TupleN.  Bump max for product and tuple.
2. Add case to Tuple (which needs ProductN). This works because the code that emits the companion module cuts you some slack by truncating params to MaxFunctionArity.  I think Namers should check MaxProductArity, and companions should stop extending Function at MaxFunctionArity. Also gen and compile FunctionN, without the tupled and uncurried, which would require applying N args. (isFunctionType is still false for FunctionN.)
3. Finally bump MaxFunctionArity and gen full Function support.

The formatting of this REPL session is mangled by x windows wrapping on Function26, but you get the idea:

```
    scala> val f: Function26 = null

    console>:7: error: trait Function26 takes type parameters

    scala> val f: Function26 = 

    y:Int,z:Int) => a+z 
    f: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function26>

    scala> f(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2)
    res0: Int = 3
```

Comment: This is great! I'll try to apply this to 2.9.2 now. Have you managed to build distribution?

Comment: I'm still puzzled - what commands do you run to get that work? `ant build`, `ant replacelocker`, or something other?

Comment: Hm. Then it seems I have a simpler solution - that works for 2.9.2, and does not require such hoops - see my third edit. The only thing I failed to figure out was copying of *.jar to lib by hand :)

Comment: I got it working! I described the whole process (and provided a working script) in my blog: http://rogach-scala.blogspot.com/2012/09/scala-with-bigger-tuples.html

Comment: Well, I think that I can work around that as well, but for now it seems I spent enough time on this problem - and it works for 2.9.2. When 2.10 goes stable, then I'll think about this once more.